# Upload file to CKAN with ckanapi (Python)

Tags: python, api, ckan

```
import ckanapi

try:

        ckan = ckanapi.RemoteCKAN(serverurl,
            apikey='myapikeyhere',
            user_agent='useragenthere')

    res = ckan.action.resource_create(
        package_id='2ad3c9de-502c-403a-8b03-bfc619697ff2',
        #url='url',
        #revision_id='revid',
        description='my first upload with CKANAPI',
        upload=open('./upload.csv')
    )

except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(str(e.error_dict))
```

It fails with:

> Field errors: {u'url': [u'Missing value'], u'__type': u'Validation Error'}

They made url a required attribute in this discussion on GitHub:
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/1641

**So what is the expected value of the url attribute?**
If it's expecting the url to the local file, it's not hosted.
And I cannot supply the url of the file on CKAN, because the resourceid was not created, yet.

PS: When passing an arbitrary value for the url attribute, the upload succeeds.
It makes no sense to require the url attribute. Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 0):

That's, in my opinion, a bug in CKAN. I've created a issue to track it at https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/2769. I've also wrote a pull request on ckanapi to abstract this bug at https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi/pull/74.

As a workaround in the mean time, you can set the `url` to an empty string.